# jQuery FullCalendar programmatically change event rendering color

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm developing a multi-user version of the jQuery plugin fullcalendar. Each user has a unique color. You change user in a drop-down. So, I can assign a color for the users existing events.

The problem is when you render a new event, the color assigned to the 'eventColor' property of fullCalendar on initialize is not changed.

Let's say user 1 has, for example blue events. I initialize the fullCalendar with 'eventColor' blue. When and I change to user 2 who has yellow events, the rendered event still shows a blue event. I would like the event to be yellow from the moment I start dragging until i release the event.

I tried changing the event rendering color with $('.calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'eventColor', 'NEW_COLOR_HERE'); but that doesn't work.

Anyone found themselves in the same situation and came up with the solution? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function option(name, value) {

        if (value === undefined) {
           return options[name];
        }
        if (name == 'height' || name == 'contentHeight' || name == 'aspectRatio') {
            options[name] = value;
            updateSize();
        }
       // So I added these lines to the plugin and voila, it works like charm!
       if(name == 'eventColor') {
           options[name] = value;
       }
}
```

Call it in your script by

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'eventColor', '#NEW_COLOR_HERE');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the global color, try `rerenderEvents`.

But looks like you may want to just set the [event](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) `color` property of one event (say, from `eventClick`), then call `updateEvent`.

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for fast response!
rerenderEvents won't work. The best would be if I could change the global eventColor when the user changes. Shouldn't this work with calendarObject.fullCalendar('option', 'eventColor', '#fefefe'); ?

I figured out how to change the event color when you release a event and the renderEvent callback is fired. But while holding the mouse and dragging the event renders with the global color.

Answer (score 0):

One way to programmatically change an event's color, first retrieve the event (based on its id) with `clientEvents`, change its color and finally re-render the event with `updateEvent`:

```
event = $('#full-calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', event_id)
event.color = 'red'
$('#full-calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event)
```